# How to use Fiddler to get POST arguments for automatic form submission?

Tags: forms, fiddler, submission

http://reserve.apple.com/WebObjects/ProductReservation.woa/wa/reserveProduct?lang=en&country=US&prelaunch=ALL

Apple seems to use AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) to dynamically populate the drop down menu when users submitting the form. When viewing the HTML source, value for the HTML Select Option is [Object Code]

How to use Fiddler to get the real value submitted so that I can write an automatic form submission script?

I downloaded Fiddler and set up breakpoint on POST and XmlHttpRequest. But I do not know exactly how to debug through Fiddler (first time to use it).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need breakpoints for it. Let it run and look at right pane of Fiddler. There is "inspectors" tab, you are interested in "Web Forms" sub-tab that will show information you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I clicked one row that is listed as HTTP 200 and on the right side I saw the arguments. It seems that Apple encrypted the value.

Comment: Note that Fiddler have built-in encoder-decoder that can deal with several popular encodings (base64, %-encoding) - "Encoder" button is on toolbar.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the encrypted value is session related and is good for only a short period of time. That's a challenge for writing an automatic form submission script in this case.